# Is checking for $second === 60 enough to circumvent the 2015 leap second bug?

Tags: php, debugging

I don't have any way to test this aside from basic coding logic of, yes if the second is Boolean equal (===) to 60, it is 60 and cannot be mistaken for another number, therefore any encapsulated function will run only during that leap second.

I posted something to that effect and I realize I may have been mistaken.

```
if ( $second === 60 )
{
   // perform needed code, show error msg, etc
   die();
}
```

*$second* being a call to the languages date function to determine the second

If this is on the top of a scripts main file, would it prevent any miscalculations from happening by simply not running the rest of the script during that 1 extra second? What about timestamps used in destructors?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: PHP, not the best example but as far as functionality the language shouldn't matter too much.